# How to make european site load faster in Asia?

Tags: hosting, cdn

I've got some client who is located in Thailand (Bangkok and Pattaya, ISP True Internet) and our saas is located in Germany (hetzner.de). Time to time they've got issues that system is unavailable (happend 2 times, actually, but it was few hours). But even when it is available - server's got long ping. Problem is in network routes. Obviously it is too long.

So the question is:

Is there any kind of service which can make our service working faster in Asia without moving a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet routing is not a fixed process set in stone. When you send data, usually not the fastest, but the cheapest route is choosen. Generally, the rule of thumb is the more you pay for routing, the faster it gets. The problem here usually is that most people don't even know that you can change how your data is routed.
Companies which can help you here operate so called Content Deliver Networks (CDN). Suggesting individual companies here would be out of scope for stackoverflow. Googling for the above term will help you.

You can make contracts with these network operating companies and they will transmit your data over a faster route or at higher priority. This is a very standard solution for many websites which need to be accessible at good speed from different continents.

Comment: Actually the CDN will not change the routing but they will put your content on servers closer to the target audience. The end result is the same though :-)